# Java refire loop after IF statement is completed

Tags: java, loops, user-input

I'm trying to make a simple text based adventure as an exercise on beginner java, but I've ran into a problem, and after a long time of searching I decided to just ask it.
I want to know how to refire this loop after IF statement has been answered, eg. user inputs: "Help", help tab shows up and user can enter another command. 
I'm clueless as to why this doesn't work, so any help would be much appreciated.

```
boolean loopone = false;
    do {
    System.out.println(name + " is standing in a forest, covered in slime goo.");
    String cmdone = in.next();
    if (cmdone.equals("Help")) {
        System.out.println("---------Help---------");
        System.out.println("Type: [Help] to view help");
        System.out.println("Type: [Turn] to turn, syntax: [Turn (direction)] left, right and backward are the possible directions");
        System.out.println("Type: [Enter] to go through an entrance");
        System.out.println("Type: [Slay] to kill stuff");
        System.out.println("Type: [Take] to take stuff");
        System.out.println("Typing: [/rocket smallbrains] has no effect here");
        return;
        }
        else if (cmdone.equals("Enter")){
            System.out.println("Enter what?");  
            String conone = in.next();
            if (conone.equals("Forest")  || conone.equals("The forest")){
                System.out.println("You're already in the forest, dummy!");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("I don't know where that is");
            }

        }
        else if (cmdone.equals("Turn right")){
            System.out.println("You turn right");
        }
    continue;
    }while (loopone = false);
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue is you need to make this:

`}while (loopone = false);`

this:

`}while (loopone == false);`

Otherwise, you just need to make sure that you are setting `loopone` to false in each of the `if` statements. When you want to exit, you set `loopone` to true (`loopone = true`).

Comment: Thanks Blaine, I'm using ( loopone = false ) after each if statement of which I want it to return to the top now. Works fine.

Comment: I don't see you assigning `loopone` anywhere, except the in `while (loopone = false);`. This will always return true, and will create an infinite loop.